# Given a PreOrder traversal of an AVL tree. Is the tree Unique?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash, avl-tree, preorder

I'm working with AVL trees for a class.

I need to identify any given tree with a hash, to build that hash I was thinking of finding the preorder traversal of all the elements in the tree and after that building the hash by concatenating the hash's of each element.

Firstly I wanted to make sure there are no repeat AVLtrees for the same preorder string. Even though I haven't found a counterexample I'm really not too sure about it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are all elements in each tree different?

Answer (score 2):

A BST (Binary Search Tree) on distinct elements is uniquely determined by its preorder traversal list L: this can be shown by induction.

Indeed:

1. the root r must be the first element of L.
2. the left sub tree of r must contain all elements less than r, and its preorder traversal is the sublist of L containing these elements: thus the left sub tree is uniquely determined, by induction.
3. same for the right sub tree of r

This result also holds for an AVL, since it is a special type of BST.